# Indent lambda function body in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, checkstyle, formatter

I have this example code that I want to pass some checkstyle rules but my formatter is not properly set up.

I just want an extra indent to lambda function body and change location of its right bracket `}`

This is what my code looks currently when I format it (`Ctrl + Alt + L`)

```
Optional.ofNullable(customerClient.
    getActiveCustomers()).map(customer -> {
    String firstName = customer.getFirstName();
    String lastName = customer.getLastName();
    return firstName + " " + lastName;
}).orElse(null);
```

but I need to change my formatter so that the code would look like this:

```
Optional.ofNullable(customerClient.
    getActiveCustomers()).map(customer -> {
        String firstName = customer.getFirstName();
        String lastName = customer.getLastName();
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
).orElse(null);
```

Comment: Note: while this code could be more concisely written using `customer -> customer.getFirstName() + " " + customer.getLastName()`, this is not the point here.

Comment: I just wanted to give it some lines in the lambda body to show what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Right. It was just a comment so a potential discussion doesn't revolve around "But you could have written it this way", which totally misses the point. (I'm sorry, I use eclipse and I have no idea which Intellij knobs you have to knob.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-147715). Feel free to vote.